# R Passing a variable into an enclosed string

Tags: r, string

This may seem like a simple problem to solve, but it's beyond me. I have the following enclosed string

```
'{"foo":"bar","x":"<SOME VAR>"}'
```

I want to pass a variable into the place of `<SOME VAR>`. What would be the best way to achieve this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can't you use `gsub`? `string_name <- gsub(pattern = "<SOME VAR>", replacement = variable, x = string_name)` where string_name is the name of your example string

Comment: Have you tried something like this? `y <- 25; paste0('{"foo":"bar","x":"', y, '"}')`.

Comment: @sweetmusicality That worked perfectly. Can you post that as an answer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(re-posting this as an answer as requested - glad to know it worked!)

can't you use `gsub`?

```
string_name <- gsub(pattern = "<SOME VAR>", replacement = variable, x = string_name)
```

where string_name is the name of your example string

Answer (score 1):

Can you store it as a list like:

```
a <- list("foo" = "bar", "x" = "<SOME VAR>")
```

If yes you could just fill it using the `$`operator:

```
a$x <- 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string is, in fact, a JSON object and thus you can use any JSON parser in R to convert your data to a `data.frame`, easy to manipulate.

```
library(jsonlite)

x <- '{"foo":"bar","x":"<SOME VAR>"}'
df <- fromJSON(x)
my_value <- "This is the value I want"
df$x <- my_value
df

#$foo
#[1] "bar"
#
#$x
#[1] "This is the value I want"
```

You can convert the `data.frame` again to JSON with:

```
toJSON(df, auto_unbox = TRUE)
```